# Inserting Non duplicate data into a table from Parent table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables :   OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP and #OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP1

with same columns on both the table as :

```
Customer_Part_Number,
Lear_Part_Number,
Shipping_ID,
Customer_Name,
Effective_Date,
End_Date,Change_ID,
PO_Number,
PO_Price
```

I have successfully copied all the data to table #OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP1 from table OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP.
But my scenario stucks when the records are same in table OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP and I don't want it to get it inserted to table #OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP1.
Just need to insert non duplicate records.

Answer (score 1):

This inserts records only which are in OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP but not in OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP1

```
INSERT INTO OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP1
SELECT * FROM OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP 
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP1
```

Comment: THATS TRUE, BUT I WANT UNIQUE  RECORDS TO BE INSERTED IN TABLE  OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP1 FROM TABLE OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP  INSPITE OF DUPLICATE ENTRY IN  TABLE OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP .

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to have a unique id for each row. Then you can select from Table 1 (OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP) and insert into Table 2 (#OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP1) where it doesn't already exist.

> INSERT INTO #OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP1
>   SELECT *
>   FROM OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP 
>   WHERE OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP.[Unique_ID] NOT IN 
>   (SELECT Unique_ID FROM #OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP1)

Noel

Comment: I like @TheGameiswar's answer better than mine.

Comment: I just need to insert the unique value from Table OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP to OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP1.

Comment: I have tried this querry :
INSERT INTO OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP1 (
TENANT_ID,
CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,
LEAR_PART_NUMBER,
SHIPPING_ID,
CUSTOMER_NAME,
PROGRAM_NAME,
EFFECTIVE_DATE,
END_DATE,
CHANGE_ID,
PO_NUMBER,
PO_PRICE)
SELECT TENANT_ID,
CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,
LEAR_PART_NUMBER,
SHIPPING_ID,
CUSTOMER_NAME,
PROGRAM_NAME,
EFFECTIVE_DATE,
END_DATE,
CHANGE_ID,
PO_NUMBER,
PO_PRICE FROM OSUSR_1SV_STAGING_FTP
EXCEPT SELECT TENANT_ID,
CUSTOMER_PART_NUMBER,
LEAR_PART_NUMBER,
SHIPPING_ID,
CUSTOMER_NAME,
PROGRAM_NAME,
EFFECTIVE_DATE,
END_DATE,
CHANGE_ID,
PO_NUMBER,
PO_PRICE
 FROM OSUSR_1SV_QAD_PO_DATA